# Use CSS to make background-image above background-color in a list

Tags: css, z-index, background-image, background-color

This is the code

```
<ul>
    <li class="test">
         <a href="#">
            <h2>Blah</h2>
            <p>Blah Blah Blah</p>
         </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, my list already has some styling, for example, I set the background-color for it.

Now in the class "test", I also set a background-image.

My question is I want to make the background-image stays above the background-color and I dont know how to achieve this. I tried with z-index but I think it is not applicable for background-image.

Please take a look at the image

[image: Output]

Edit: This is the CSS Code

For example, this is the styling for my list

```
#sidebar ul li{  
    background:#ccf;
}
```

And this is the styling for the class test

```
.test{
    background-image: url('img/big_tick.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right;
    -moz-background-size: 30%;
    -webkit-background-size: 30%;
    background-size: 30%;    
    margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with his set up: http://jsfiddle.net/LHmfT/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `!important` attribute to your `background-image`. Like this:

```
.test a{
background-image: url('img/big_tick.png') !important;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: bottom right;
-moz-background-size: 30%;
-webkit-background-size: 30%;
background-size: 30%;    
margin-right: 30px;
```

}

I have an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LHmfT/11/)

EDIT: I changed the class to `.test a` to reflect the actual styling scheme

Comment: I tried to put the !important but it still stays behind the background-color.

@alpa I tried to change background to background-color, but it still doesnt work.

For the list, I followed this tutorial from Nettuts
[link]http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/create-a-sticky-note-effect-in-5-easy-steps-with-css3-and-html5/

You can take a look at the link to know more about the CSS for the list
Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What browser are you using? The `!important` flag is working in both Chrome and IE over here. If you post more of your styling for the list, that might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Im testing this on FF 8.0 and Chrome 16, and Im still facing the problem. The styling for the list is in the link http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/create-a-sticky-note-effect-in-5-easy-steps-with-css3-and-html5/. Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: I see now! The problem comes from the fact that the background is being set in a. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LHmfT/11/ and I've updated my answer to reflect the fix. Let me know how it works. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works flawlessly now. I'm so dumb, setting the background for different elements T__T, again thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Try: adding specificity to the .test class: `#sidebar ul li.test`

Or, better yet, if it's possible, add `background-color` to the .test class, and get rid of the element selector altogether.

I would avoid using !important unless you absolutely need it. In the long run, using it will make editing your css a pain. Instead of using !important, I suggest learning about specificity: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/inheritancecascade

Comment: This just changes the position of the background image but does not make it stay above of the background-color

Comment: Try: adding specificity to the test class: #sidebar ul li.test  Or, better yet, if it's possible, add background-color to the test class, and get red of the element selector altogether.