# CSS: How to bring background image to the front?

Tags: css

I was already looking at [CSS: How to make background-image above background-color in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491958/css-how-to-make-background-image-above-background-color-in-a-list) and tried the `!important` attribute but without success.

I have [this](http://www.mensch-jinn-dajjal.net/) example page where I would like to bring the yellow book cover which I use as a background image in front of the navigation bar below.

[image]

The code I am using is the following:

```
.home-link {
  background: url(http://www.mensch-jinn-dajjal.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Buchtitel.gif) no-repeat !important;
  background-size: 180px 200px !important;
  background-position: 400px 80px !important;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```

Any idea why it is not coming to the front?

I also tried to assign the navbar a negative z-index without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` won't work in this case; z-index is meant for those elements which are stacked one over another i.e. they have overlapping top and left, which is not in your case. 
Html is working the way it should i.e. flow layout,

this is your markup outhere on your site :

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
     <a class="home-link" href="...</a> <-- Link containing the image-->
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar"> <!-- navigation bar -->
    </div><!-- #navbar -->
</header>
```

clearly, your anchor and navigation bar are placed one after another, they are rendered exactly like that.

So, if you want to overlap your image, you need to make your image  `position:absolute`. I would recommend, create a independent `img` tag and make it position absolute and place it exactly where you want, with relative top and left, so that it adjusts itself according to the resolution.

see this simple illustration of z-index :[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6U3T/)

in this, we have four `float:left, position:absolute` divisions, by-default, when no z-index is given to any of them, the one that was present in the last in the flow, was the visible color, but as you give higher z-index to anyone of them(first one in example), it becomes the visible color

Comment: Thanks Manish. I found your solution the best in this case. Adding a separate `<img>` tag works perfectly and is a good workaround the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited the old post**

Just change these properties then your good to go. since you provided very small piece of code. it was hard to figure and explain. but do these following changes. this will get you what you want. and you have to do some alignments re-touch again

```
.site-header {
    background: url(http://www.mensch-jinn-dajjal.net/wp-       content/uploads/2013/12/header-without-book-1600x230.jpg) no-repeat scroll top;
    background-size: 1600px auto;
    z-index: 1; //updated here
 }

 .navbar {
     background-color: #DD2A0F;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     padding-right: 80px;
     position: absolute;  //updated here
     top: 200px;  //updated here
     z-index: -2; //updated here
  }


 .site-header .home-link {
     color: #141412;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     max-width: 1080px;
     min-height: 280px; //updated here
     padding: 0 20px;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

**The Snapshot is here.**

[image]

Comment: Why is this property a problem? I need this property to position the background image where I want it to be (which is in the free space between the navigation elements `Bewertungen` and `Kontakt`)

Comment: Post Edited, check that out

Comment: if i understand correctly he wants the yellow logo to be shown full view. if there is a positioning problem.

Comment: @Kirk i dont think so. he is trying to bring the yellow part infront of menu bar.

Comment: Thanks for your solution Kirk! I tried it out and it seemed to work. However, I followed the other suggestions and added a separate `<img>` tag which I can then put in front of the navbar with a relative position and a higher z-index.

Comment: well, i gave the solution based on you request, if i do that i would also follow the seperate img tag thing

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies not where you think. In fact `a.home-link` is really on the front, but it does not overlap the navbar. And you really dont want it to, because you could no longer use the `navbar` to navigate when the menu buttons are situated under the link `a.home-link`

In order to achieve what you liked to, you need to separate your `a.home-link` in two:

1. Have one `a` element represent the link with the text
2. Have a second `a` element represent the book cover

Just general remarks about your css-coding style:

- Use `!important` only in exceptional cases. `!important` should not be a way to invalidate basic css inheritance principles. Conceive your document structure with styling in mind, and you'll (almost) never need `!important` any more. Don't use `!ipmortant` often, because (1) you cannot override it, (2) it leads to unmaintanable css code.
- Use well chosen z-index values: why use `99999` if `2` is already bigger than `1` ? And if you want later something before `99999`, will you use `999999` ?

Answer (score 0):

Stacking order of elements in CSS is controlled by the `position` property and `z-index` property. From looking at your code, you do not have a `position` property declared either on the `.home-link` div or the navbar below it.

I would try adding `position: relative` to `.home-link` for starters. Then you might have to play around with the positioning and `z-index` of the navbar.